# Problems when using Lcc-Win compiler

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am new to programming here and pushing my limits to learn C as my first language. I have installed a compiler LCC-Win. However when I created a code with two or more functions and compile it, I always stuck to the problem where "compiler has stopped working" and file not created although the compiler says it is. Is this only me or should I change to other compiler?
By the way I am using a Windows 7 64-bit.

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Yeah, if your compiler crashes all the time, you should probably use a different compiler.

Comment: Does your compiler produce any error message or just aborts without notification? If the latter, you should probably use a different compiler.

Comment: It does not produce any error, instead it shows "File Created". If I were to change compiler, any recommendations?